# Can I hide PS Vita friend notifications?

Tags: ps-vita

The notifications that pop up when your friends come online are very disruptive. Is there any way to turn off the notifications while remaining signed in? I didn't see any such option in the Friends or Settings apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do this. You can turn off the notification light and sound in settings but cannot physically turn off the notification. This is, however, a feature that is being discussed on the PS Vita forums to be suggested for future software releases.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work at the current moment. They just put a useless check box for it for them to not procrastinate on it. (Even though they probably will anyways.) I tried also turning off the light and sound for notifications, yet it STILL notifies with a light on the PS Button, however it never makes a sound in standby for a notification.